# SGDClassifier with no featured names, hands on ml

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I was reading the chapter 3 of the book "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow" and i'm having a lot of bugs in my code, i'm using google colab but i'm getting an error when i try predicting to see if my training was successful

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

mnist = fetch_openml("mnist_784",version=1)

x,y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]

some_digit = x.to_numpy()[0] # i had to use that otherwise the x remains as a string

y = y.astype(np.uint8)

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = x[:60000], x[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:]

y_train_5 = (y_train == 5)
y_test_5 = (y_test == 5)


sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
sgd_clf.fit(x_train,y_train_5)

sgd_clf.predict([some_digit]) # the line that returns me the error
```

The last line returns me the following error in the image. [image showing the prediction error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd4QA.png)

ERROR:
`/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py:451: UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but SGDClassifier was fitted with feature names "X does not have valid feature names, but" array([ True])`

Comment: It's easier for everyone if you copy paste the error instead of just a screenshot. Also we have the same dogs in our profile pictures!

Comment: I just noticed, its predicting the right way, but i have the problem of feature names,  i don't know if its going to affect the result or if it is just a warning

Comment: Its just a warning